# Improper animation after clicking the mouse button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

When I run below code my expected output is that the player should continuosly animating and when user taps on screen the player should jump. My player's frames are diffrent and jump frames are different. I am calling frames on mouse left button click. All frames are processed but its too fast so the animation is not visible.

```
    private void OnUpdate(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
    {
        float elapsed = (float)e.ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds;
        timer5 -= elapsed;

        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap;
        TouchCollection touches = TouchPanel.GetState();

        MouseState mousestate = Mouse.GetState();

        //Texture.position += velocity;
        //if (rect.Contains(new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Point(mousestate.X, mousestate.Y)) && mousestate.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)

        if (mousestate.LeftButton==ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            {

               jump();
                jumpframe++;
                if (jumpframe > 24)
                {
                    jumpframe = 0;
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("currentframe:"+ jumpframe);
            }
        }

        if (timer5 <= 0)
        {
            playerr();
            currentframe++;
            if (currentframe > 24)
            {
                currentframe = 0;
            }
            timer5 = TIME_BET_FRAME;
        }
    }

    private void OnDraw(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
    {
        SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        //level.Draw(spriteBatch);
        rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 960, 620);
        rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 420, 300);

        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture.player[currentframe], Texture.position, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture.jumpplayer[jumpframe], Texture.jumpposition,                 Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture.jumpbtn, Texture.rect, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score", new Vector2(10, 0), Color.Gold);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }

    public void jump()
    {
        Texture.jumpposition.X = 10;
        Texture.jumpposition.Y = 243;
        Texture.position.X = -400;
        Texture.position.Y = 243;    
    }

    public void playerr()
    {
        Texture.position.X = 10;
        Texture.position.Y = 243;
        Texture.jumpposition.X = -400;
        Texture.jumpposition.Y = 243;
    }
```

Comment: You already stated the problem - "too fast". Slow down by creating timer divided job.

Comment: @Sinatr i have already used the timer5 for player.......so now can i use the same for jumpplayer???...thnx for responding

Comment: also use some more understandable variable names (instead of timer5, rect2, something2000), you will get lost after a month when project will grow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see is the loop

```
for(int i=0;i<32;i++){...}
```

which is drawing a complete jump animation at once in the `OnUpdate`.

What you can do instead:

```
bool _jump;

private void OnUpdate(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    if (mousestate.LeftButton==ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
         if(!_jump)
         {
             // start jumping
             _jump = true;
         }
         else
         {
             // jumping in progress
             _jumpframe++;
             // end of jumping check
             if(_jumpframe > 24)
             {
                 _jumpframe = 0;
                 _jump = false;
             }
         }
         jump();
    }
}
```

This should perform animation of jumping with the speed (frequency) of `OnUpdate`.

Comment: problem with intersect method of rectangle